# Exception handling, only accept specific file inputs

Tags: python, input, types, exception, filenames

This is a bit above my pay grade, so I thought I would ask on here.

My simple Python code prompts the user to enter the name of a file. However, it must be a specific type of file, or else I would like to throw an error. In this case, the files entered must be a text or CSV file, i.e. filename extensions must be `.txt` or `.csv`

```
filename = raw_input("Please enter .txt or .csv file: ")
```

I have no idea how to test for that. You begin with something like

```
def fileName():
   while True:
       try: 
           filename = raw_input("Please enter .txt or .csv file: ")
```

and then use an if statement check whether the last four characters are `.txt` or `.csv`.

What is the standard way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext

Comment: I don't think you want a `try` here. If you want to raise an exception, you don't to immediately catch the same exception, or what's the point? (But if you _do_ want a `try`, then you need at least one `except` or a `finally`. If you can't think of what you'd want to put there… then you shouldn't have a `try`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep asking until the user enters a filename with the correct extension using [str.endswith](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
def fileName():
   while True:
       filename = raw_input("Please enter .txt or .csv file: ")
       if filename.endswith((".csv",".txt"))
          return filename
       else:
            print("Extension must be .csv or .txt")
```

If you actually want to just verify the input and raise an error on bad input:

```
   def fileName():
       filename = raw_input("Please enter .txt or .csv file: ")
       if filename.endswith((".csv",".txt")):
           return filename
       raise ValueError("Extension must be .csv or .txt")
```

You don't need a try/except to check the last four  characters are either `.txt` or `.csv` but just because the filename may end with the correct extension does not mean it is a valid file or won't cause an error when opening, you should worry about catching exceptions when and if you actually open the file.

Comment: Whoah! I never knew python has a "endswith()" string method! For others checking out this post, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html
Thanks!

Comment: @JesseTrevve, no worries, you're welcome. You can pass a single string or a tuple of strings to check against.

Comment: Another quick question: How can I use the file I've entered into my code? Previously, I was using `filename`, but now it throws an error. Surely `filename = raw_input()` should define that value throughout the code, even if it is in a function.

Comment: You need to use the filename returned fron the function

Answer (score 2):

Python has great resources for doing all sorts of path manipulations. This is a good time to go ahead and get familiar with them.

See the documentation for [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) and specifically, for `os.path.splitext(path)` 
which returns a pair (root, ext) so you can test the ext (extension) value.